# update table1 with changed values in table 2

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database; *weather*, and *weatherhistorical*.
Both the tables contain the following columns: `row_names,cityid,cityname,temperature,description,speed,datetime,date,time`

The data is generated in a R dataframe, and then the dataframe is written into the *weather* table.

weather contains some weather forecast data for 3 days ahead, from a few different locations.

I want to create a statement that copies and only updates the changed data into the *weatherhistorical* table.

I have tried 
`INSERT INTO weatherhistorical 
  (row_names,cityid,cityname,temperature,description,speed,datetime,date,time)
  SELECT * FROM weather ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;`

statements, but they won't work because there isn't a proper key in the table. The datetime won't work because it has duplicate values, because there are about 8 cities, which have the same datetime in the data.

The row_names column isn't suited for a key, because it is regenerated every time the weather forecast is retrieved.

Some sample data is seen here:
[image: Some sample data]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can we simplify this somehow?  Could you just use a `WHERE` clause to identify which records need to be migrated?

Comment: If it can be simplified, that would be great. I just can't wrap my mind on how to achieve that.

Comment: I think you should keep track of which records have been inserted.  E.g. insert in batches by day.  Your current approach, if I'm not mistaken, is to insert the entire table and then try to avoid duplicates.  If nothing else, this is wasteful.

Comment: I plan to run this once or twice a day - weather is sort of a temporary table, with only batch data, that gets overwritten each time.

Comment: What about using [Mysql Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)? In this way you can keep the track of each single revision instead of running twice a day.